# Sum value if match two text in the one cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In excel formula is it possible to sum value if match two text in the one cell. I tried to use this below formula but it is showing "0" value.

[image]

Comment: Please, post your data as text, not as image. And also, define properly your input and the expected output, so somebody can help you out. I can say that it can be done with VBA for sure, but with normal Excel Formulas probably you need some tricky way around like you are trying to do.

Comment: Split your expression up and test each part separately. Perhaps FIND() with AND() may be better than SEARCH()

Comment: Foxfire And Burns And Burns: thanks for your comments next time i will try to fill data as a text. i am locking excel formula not VBA code. However, my output will be total QTY of black pen.

=SUMIFS(B2:B5,A2:A5,FIND({"*Black*","*Pen*"},A2:A5))

i used this code but is shown result "0".

Answer (score 2):

Try this formula in cell D2,

> =SUMPRODUCT(B2:B10,--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$2,A2:A10))))

You can also add multiple conditions by adding another array in the formula

> =SUMPRODUCT(B18:B100,--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Black",A18:A100))),--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Cross",A18:A100))))

B2:B10 - Contains your text

A2:A10 - Contains your values

C2     - The text that you want to find

Comment: Mr. Imran at first thanks for your comment and this ans is shown is correct result. but problem is i need to search by text because sometime my product description not input this way. is use example: material: Pen, Color: Black, Manufacturer: CROSS........

Comment: Put your search criteria in double quotes e.g. "Red Pen" instead of $C$2